# How to fill this table in Vuejs with Laravel-vue-datatable?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how does this library work:

https://vuejsexamples.com/a-vue-js-datatable-component-for-laravel-that-works-with-bootstrap/

And it seems it's working it's loading the search box and the "per page" numbers, but it seems that is expecting to get a json objet through "url" for the content, how can I test this? How can I fill it just to test it?

```
<template>
  <div class="container my-documents">
    <data-table
        url=""
        :per-page="perPage"
        :columns="columns">
    </data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  components: {

  },
  data() {
        return {
            perPage: ['10', '25', '50'],
            columns: [
                {
                    label: 'ID',
                    name: 'id',
                    filterable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'Name',
                    name: 'name',
                    filterable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: 'Email',
                    name: 'email',
                    filterable: true,
                },
                {
                    label: '',
                    name: 'View',
                    filterable: false,
                },
            ]
        }
    },
  methods: {
  }
};
</script>
```

On my app.js

```
import DataTable from 'laravel-vue-datatable';
Vue.use(DataTable);
```

PS: do you know a better way (easier and lighter) to get this table tools for laravel-vue?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like that.